# Preserve non-break space &nbsp in jQuery trim function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trim only regular whitespace and preserve &nbsp non-break spaces. What is my best bet?

**Update:** By trim, I mean either leading or trailing. I specifically need to eliminate leading whitespace other than &nbsp, but I will appreciate answers that do the same for also trailing or just trailing.

Comment: like 'string.replace(" ", "")'?

Comment: jQuery's `trim()` only trims leading and following space ?

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but you might avoid downvotes if you added example input and output. I assume you want to preserve leading and/or trailing non-breaking spaces but it's not immediately obvious from the question (which is why people are confused).

Comment: hi @randomstring, could you please add an example of what you want to achieve, and perhaps sample code for what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: @SayemAhmed leading and/or trailing

Comment: @adeneo it trims &nbsp which I do not want

Comment: @jillesdewit i have updated it: "   &nbsp;foobar&nbsp;   " -> "&nbsp;foobar&nbsp;"

Comment: all, i thought the semantics of "trim" are pretty clear: trailing space if not also leading space. the focus is on preserving &nbsp; which jquery trims away. nevertheless, i have added an update to clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, neither the native trim or jQuery's trim seem to remove `&nbsp;` from a string -> http://jsfiddle.net/FyFyS/ If the string is present in the DOM, the `&nbsp;` will be converted like any enitity to it's character equalent, which is a space, and you can't really tell the difference between a space and space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is the content of an HTML tag you can cheat a bit, using:

```
var result = $( '#element' ).html().trim();
```

which will not trim `&nbsp;` because it will literally be `&nbsp;` in the string.

If the string is not in a tag you could try:

```
var result = $( '<p>' + the_string + '</p>' ).html().trim();
```

which should do the same thing.

Comment: tentatively accepting because this is on verge of being closed. please don't mind if i change the acceptance to a better answer later. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace all white spaces with blank.

```
 var dest = 'test value';
 result_val=dest.split(" ").join("");
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smxFV/3/)

Comment: hi, i didn't do a -1, but i will upvote you to reverse it. i think you did not address the &nbsp part

Comment: Anybody simply can understand that it only trim regular white spaces. that's why i didn't mentioned specially..:)

Comment: however, i meant leading and trailing (trim usually means that i think..) so can't accept it

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove empty characters in the middle of the string, you can use this (note the first parameter means any amount of whitespace but shouldn't match an  ):

```
var newString = s.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

If not (meaning only remove white space at the start/end of the string), you can use

```
var newString = s.trim();
```

Comment: sorry if I was not clear but "trim" has leading and trailing semantics

Comment: i did not downvote you. i also did not read the trim part of your solution, but neither of your solutions addresses the "non-break space" aspect of the question which is in the title. i don't downvote anyone who answers my question. in this case i would upvote you back to compensate for whoever downvoted, but your answer does not address the key aspect of the question at all.. let me know if i missed any non-break space part.